# Typescript optional property type generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

I would like my function to take any kind of objects but if the objet have a property 'id' making sure that is is either a string or a number.

Here is the minimal example:

```
interface FnItem {
  id?: string | number;
};

function fn<T extends FnItem>(item: T, callback: (item: T) => void) {
  console.log(item.id);
  callback(item)
};

fn({ name: 'Michel' }, item => item.name);
fn({ name: 'Michel', id: 12 }, item => item.name);
```

It throws this error

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FnItem'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'FnItem'
---
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FnItem
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: fn needs to specify the generic so should be `fn<YourType>()`. If you just want an interface then you don't need the generic. The signature can simple be `fn(item:FnItem)`

Comment: I have clarify the minimum example, I hope it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `FnItem` might be either any object with any properties or any object where `id` is `number|string` I would rather stick with this solution:

```js
type FnItem = Record<string, unknown>

type IdValidation<Obj extends Record<string, unknown>> =
    Obj extends { id: infer Id } ? Id extends string | number ? Obj : Obj & { id: never } : Obj;

function fn<T extends FnItem,>(item: IdValidation<T>, callback: (item: IdValidation<T>) => void) {
    console.log(item.id);
    callback(item)
};

fn({ name: 'Michel' }, item => item.name);
fn({ name: 'Michel', id: 12 }, item => item.id);

fn({ name: 'Michel' }, item => item.ya); // error
fn({ name: 'Michel', id: [] }, item => item.id); // id is highlighted as a wrong property
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgSWBAtlAvFAShAxgewCcATAHgGdhCBLOAcwBooBXOAaznwHc4A+AWABQQ0JCgJiANQCGAG2rFpwavjikA8gCMAVlAgAPZHGLlseImUo16TVh259eGIVFdQtug0ZNQA3lAUALgC4ADMIQnFiKABfKAB+KL1DCGNTK1o6KAAfKDhmFE0IhPcdKGCPKAAyPwDiYLgIADdiuIqdAG4hIVDWXGVVKFC1ABVk71N4JFQGXgAKamQUYIkZeUUB0d4mXDlZTWlcNmCFpZWpOQUlFS2ASgwnJvwFe98XNwI4cnxZCAA6WT4OinVB-F5dQRuKC7WT7Q5sEEoW5CGIQnpwOb+ODSFAQYIAcgAstRcAALCCyfGxJiLVAPAJLP7Y3G3CHDTF5HF4qBEknkyk0+pQACMACZqQy6egnLSUGDiKzuoJ2ViuQTiWSKVSYjSlvTZX8QNJWVAAPSmvSEQhEdEc5nc3magV1YIAbQAuhLZfrGeCzRaFAFTKTqHRSfIw8hiEA)

Since first argument might be any object, we should allow passing `Record<string,unknown>` which in turn disables our constraint regarding `id` being `number|string`. This is why I have added `IdValidation` utility type. It just checks whether `id` property meets condition or not. If it meets - leave `id` as is, otherwise - replace `id` type with `never`. Using `never` allows you to highlight only incorrect property which makes it easy to read and understand.

If you are interested in TS validation techniques you can check my articles [here](https://catchts.com/validators) and [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation)

Comment: For anyone tying to understand what's going on in there see [TypeScript conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you all you need. `name` doesn't exist on your `FnItem` type. You can fix it by adding the property or adding an index signature if you want to add arbitrary keys like so:

```
interface FnItem {
  id?: string | number;
  [key: string]: any; // or whatever types you accept
};
```

As for the generic, I can't tell what you need it for at the moment, as you could simply define the function as

```
function fn(item: FnItem): void
```

Comment: You don't need to implement everything in the interface. That kinda defaults the object of interfaces

Comment: It works however as @Liam say, I don't want to allow accessing other property of the object. For example
```function fn<T extends FnItem>(item: T, callback: (item: T) => void) {
  console.log(item.yaya);
};``` It should throw an error. With your solution it just allow it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a generic then you need to tell the function what concrete type implements your interface:

```js
interface FnItem {
  id?: string | number;
};

function fn<T extends FnItem>(item: T,  callback: (item: T) => void) {
  console.log(item.id);
  callback(item);
};

fn<myType>({ name: 'Michel', id: 12 }, (item:myType)  => { console.log(item.name); });
fn<myType>({ name: 'Michel' }, (item:myType) => { console.log(item.name); });

class myType implements FnItem
{
    name: string = "";
    id?: number;
}
```

[Compiled example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIgJKQLbIN4CwAUMssACYD8AXMgM5hSgDmyAPsiAK7YBG0AbmIBfIUWIwuIBGGAB7EMhggAPABVkEAB6QQ5Omkw4AfAApgOWmoA0pBHAA2D3ogDWtc5eRqAlMgC8xsgAbnIUfoQkyAgKdHIOEAB0DnLMnhDYieFido7ObunYPmKixBKq2ACeapUADhBmeJxw2BC0AOQAssAIABYQDu22FLQAjABMyMK2hdRVNfV+AUF4wsXlKvN1DaZNIC1tyF09-YNTMxYZc9XbfoH4a2LECA5wdAZb9WTYtQmt4AZ0FgMsRIqRSPtWrQGEwQKx-MgAESInLgig0Tg8fhQEpAA)

Comment: I need the generic, I have updated my question to make it clearer. I don't want to define the possible property because I want this function to accept "any" type.

Comment: Added example for you answer. You still need to specify what exactly `T` is

Comment: Shouldn't it work without specifying what T is. It can determine what T is because it is the first argument.
The same way it works for `fn({ name: 'Michel', id: 12 }, item => item.name);`

Comment: The generic can sometimes be implied. And in fact in the above the compiler will figure it out, but all this is doing is the compiler populating the generic for you. You still need a concrete type if your using a generic. That's why generics exist!

Comment: Okay, however it still don't work. Let's say my type is `interface OnlyName { name: string; }`, is still throw an error `Type 'OnlyName' has no properties in common with type 'FnItem'.`

Comment: Well `OnlyName` doesn't **fully** implement the interface. Your type needs to fully implement the interface. A nullable property `id?` is still a property, so that would need to be `interface OnlyName { name: string, id?:string | number; }`

Comment: This is the problem with typescript flexible typing. IMO you should never do `string | number` as this then breaks common typing constraints. Either use a type or don't. You can't really have it both ways without getting into a mess, even if TS says you can

Comment: Ah, but that's my point. I want `fn` to be able to take types that never have `id` defined.

Comment: Then your interface is non-sensical. You'd have to use `any`

Comment: I end up removing the "extends" and doing `const {id} = item as {id?: string | number};` in the function, I guess it the cleanest way.